# pass complex text to JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have ran into a strange behavior of passing JSON from PHP to jQuery.

I have some articles (Drupal CMS articles) and I need to push them into the environment. 
First solution worked, while the articles was pushed directly by PHP on page load. But as my work works with more than one CMS, it takes too much time to load them all, so I need to use ajax to load one specific project at time.

now, jquery looks like this:

```
function doLoadArticles() {

for (var i = 0; i< projectdata[1].length; i++){
 $.ajax({
         data: {ip:projectdata[0]["ip"], login:projectdata[0]["login"], pass:projectdata[0]["pass"], db:projectdata[0]["db"], datatype:projectdata[1][i], aj:"aj", fc:"doLoadArticles"},
         type: "post",
         url: "dataFunnel.php",
         success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
           //console.log(jQuery.parseJSON( data )) ;

         }


         });  

}

}
```

Then, on PHP side is this code:

```
function doLoadArticles(){

   $projdata;

  $conn = new mysqli($_POST['ip'], $_POST['login'], $_POST['pass'], $_POST['db']);
     // Check connection
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("<div style='position:absolute; top:0;left:0; background:white;'>Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error." <br><br>Plese try reload the page</div>");
     break;
     }
    else{}


     $sql = "Select node_revision.title, node_revision.nid, node.language, field_revision_body.body_value, field_revision_body.bundle, node_revision.timestamp  
      from field_revision_body 
      LEFT JOIN node_revision ON field_revision_body.revision_id=node_revision.vid 
      LEFT JOIN node ON field_revision_body.revision_id=node.vid 
      where field_revision_body.bundle='".$_POST['datatype']."' AND node_revision.status=1 AND node.language='cs' 
      ORDER BY field_revision_body.revision_id DESC LIMIT 10";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

       if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          // error_log("true"); 
         // output data of each row
            $j =0;
          while($row_a = $result->fetch_assoc()) {    


        $projdata[$j]["title"] = $row_a["title"] ;           
        $projdata[$j]["timestamp"] = $row_a["timestamp"] ;
        $projdata[$j]["bundle"] = $row_a["bundle"] ;
        $projdata[$j]["body_value"] = $row_a["body_value"];
        $projdata[$j]["nid"] = $row_a["nid"];
        $projdata[$j]["language"] = $row_a["language"];  

            $j++;

            }
      }

      echo json_encode($projdata);


}
```

The problem is, that the data are there, only the passing itself does not work .. (probably because of some buged conversion?)

if I do

```
echo print_r($projdata);
```

[image]
it will pass the data, but not in usable way (ignore the broken chars, that is another not related problem, the data are thare, that is what matters)

However, as it is clear, I need it in form that I can work with, so I need json.
But if I use

```
echo json_encode($projdata);
```

it will pass some "broken nothing"
[image]

So is there any my mistake I am not aware of, or it is really some kind of bug in PHP implementation?
(by the way, I run on PHP 5.6 on MS IIS7)

Or any other way possible, how to load data dynamically without the json conversion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are getting the `1` at the end of your `print_r()` because you are running `echo print_r()`. You're essentially echoing out a function, which returns `true`. The `1` is a string representation of the value `true`. `print_r()` outputs content to the page on its own, and does not need to be used in conjunction with `echo`. Simply writing `print_r($projdata)` will fix that issue.

Comment: @ObsidianAge why not make this an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: hi, thanks for info, good to know for other cases, but was just a side question. the core of the problem still exists, while json_encode will not return json, but void parameter. `print_r` was just for demonstration, that the data-gathering part works well. I still need to pass the data to jquery object, which is not working... And for just to be sure, I have tried not ECHO, but only `json_encode($projdata)` and it is not working as well

Comment: but yes, I know that I might create some misunderstanding by that. I will edit it...

Comment: @Zorak -- can you please try `json_encode(array_values($projdata))`?

Comment: You're looking for some SQL injection, eh?

Comment: @ObsidianAge tried, aaaaaaaaand nope, still void :(